# Разделитель чанков не работает так как нужно!

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции

Здравствуйте у меня есть функция:

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(length) {
    return this.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"\n").match(new RegExp('[^]{1,' + +length + '}', 'g'));
  }
```

И я использую её так:

```
String.chunk(1024).forEach(chunk => {
        embed.addField(`** **`,`\`\`\`js\n${chunk}\`\`\``)
      });
```

В филд влезает 1024 символа,но почему-то я получаю иногда ошибку:

```
embed.fields[2].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length.
```

Что я делаю не так,ведь если я поставлю 960 то всё ок,и да в филд точно влезает 1024 символа,есть подозрение на \n т-к когда я его делю то он считается за 1 символ,а дискорд может принимать за 2!

Так же есть подозрение на то что функция делит лишь 1 раз

Т-к никогда не присылает fields[1],а всегда 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причиной оказались

```
`\`\`\`js\n${chunk}\`\`\``
```

Т-к они тоже символы,простите за то что потратил ваше время!